# Horizontal iScroll Won't Work

Tags: javascript, css, iscroll

I want to make a horizontal scroller using iScroll but it wont work. I get the attributes on the correct divs but am unable to scroll.
Here's the js:

```
//called on onload
var levelPackScroller;
function init() {
    levelPackScroller = new IScroll('#levelButtonPreScroller')
    levelPackScroller.refresh()
}
```

html:

```
<div id="levelButtonPreScroller">
    <div class="levelButtonScroller" id="levelButtonScroller">
         //bunch of <divs> go inside here
         <div></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.levelButtonScroller {
   width: 2800px;
   height: 938px;
}

#levelButtonPreScroller {
   position: absolute;
   height: 945px;
   width: 711px;
   overflow: hidden;
   left: 55px;
}
```

help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the iScroll documentation:

> By default only vertical scrolling is enabled. If you need to scroll
>   horizontally you have to set scrollX to true. See horizontal demo.

You should add

```
levelPackScroller = new IScroll('#levelButtonPreScroller', {
   scrollX : true
})
```

[Source](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll)

Comment: Yeah thanks - I was using the v4 syntax still ... scrollX/scrollY were reason for the last hour of /headdesking.